# Not sure on where to define and declare my structs. (Getting undeclared identifier)

Tags: c++

I believe that this is an issue of scope. All of my attempts to pass either pointers-to or the actual structs (GLface or GLpoint) are giving me undeclared identifier errors.

However both structs are clearly defined in the .h file.

NormalCalulator.h

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <GL/glut.h>


class NormalCalculator
{

struct GLpoint
{
    GLfloat x,y,z;
};

struct GLface
{
    GLfloat x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,x3,y3,z3;
};

public:
    NormalCalculator::NormalCalculator(void);
    NormalCalculator::~NormalCalculator(void);
    //put all of the face normal functions together 
    void NormalCalculator::generateFaceNormals(std::vector<GLfloat>* vertexArray, std::vector<GLubyte>* indexArray, std::vector<GLfloat>* normalArray);


private:
    //creates the line vectors from the the 3 points passed in as a part of the GLface
    void NormalCalculator::createLineVectorsFromFace(GLface facePassedIn, GLpoint* l_vec1, GLpoint* l_vec2); 
    //generates a normal vector for the 2 line vectors made by createLineVectorsFromFace
    void NormalCalculator::crossProductOfVecs(GLpoint* l_vec1, GLpoint* l_vec2, GLpoint* outPutNormal);
    //alters the normal vector so that it is of Unit length
    bool NormalCalculator::normalizeVector(GLpoint* normalVector, GLpoint* normalizedNormalVecContainer);
    GLpoint NormalCalculator::computeFaceNormal(GLface faceToNormal);
};
```

and the NormalCalculator.cpp is as follows.

According to the compiler the errors begin at my passing of GLface to the function createLineVectorsFromFace.
And in case anybody was wondering, the fact the GLface is passed as an object and not a pointer to a GLface is intentional.

```
#include "NormalCalculator.h"
#include <gl/glut.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>





void createLineVectorsFromFace( GLface facePassedIn, GLpoint* l_vec1, GLpoint* l_vec2)
{
    //from verts 1 & 2 initialize l_vec1
    l_vec1->x = facePassedIn.x1 - facePassedIn.x2;
    l_vec1->y = facePassedIn.y1 - facePassedIn.y2;
    l_vec1->z = facePassedIn.z1 - facePassedIn.z2;
    //do that same for l_vec2 from face 2 and 3
    l_vec2->x = facePassedIn.x2 - facePassedIn.x3;
    l_vec2->y = facePassedIn.y2 - facePassedIn.y3;
    l_vec2->z = facePassedIn.z2 - facePassedIn.z3;
}


void crossProductOfVecs(GLpoint* l_vec1, GLpoint* l_vec2, GLpoint* outPutNormal)
{
    //cross product dat hoe
    outPutNormal->x = (l_vec1->y * l_vec2->z) - (l_vec1->z * l_vec2->y);//x = aybz-byaz
    outPutNormal->y = (l_vec1->z * l_vec2->x) - (l_vec1->x - l_vec2->z);//y = azbx-bzax
    outPutNormal->z = (l_vec1->x * l_vec2->y) - (l_vec1->y - l_vec2->x);//z = axby-bxay
}


bool NormalCalculator::normalizeVector(GLpoint* normalVector, GLpoint* normalizedNormalVecContainer)
{
    //first we must work out the magnitude of the normal vector
    GLfloat mag = (sqrt((float) pow(normalVector->x,2) + pow(normalVector->y,2) + pow(normalVector->z,2)));

    if(mag)
    {
        normalizedNormalVecContainer->x = normalVector->x/mag;
        normalizedNormalVecContainer->y = normalVector->y/mag;
        normalizedNormalVecContainer->z = normalVector->z/mag;
        return true;
    }

    else return false;

}

GLpoint NormalCalculator::computeFaceNormal(GLface faceToNormal)
{
    //first we create a couple of container GLpoints for our 2 line vectors
    GLpoint a;
    GLpoint b;
    createLineVectorsFromFace(faceToNormal, &a, &b);
    //Create a container for our origional normal
    GLpoint firstNorm;
    //We have our line vectors, and a container. Now cross product them and put them in the container.
    crossProductOfVecs(&a, &b, &firstNorm);
    //create out last normal container
    GLpoint finalNorm;
    //normalize it
    normalizeVector(&firstNorm, &finalNorm);

    return finalNorm;

}



NormalCalculator::NormalCalculator(void)
{
}

NormalCalculator::~NormalCalculator(void)
{
}
```

This is just a wild guess, but do I need to do something with typedef?

Comment: Exactly what is the first error message, at what source line?

Comment: Is it valid to declare member functions in the class definition with qualified identifiers (extra `NormalCalculator::`) like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void createLineVectorsFromFace( ....
```

is not the same as

```
void NormalCalculator::createLineVectorsFromFace( ....
```

The compiler is right (as usual), you didn't define the member, you defined a free function.

Same goes for `crossProductOfVecs`.

Comment: In addition, NormalCalculator::createLineVectorsFromFace should not be used INSIDE the class definition of NormalCalculator.  Ie,class foo { void foo::bar( int x ); }; is bad, but class foo { void bar( int x ); }; is good.

Comment: Yakk I don't quite understand what you mean by class definition. Do you mean that in the .h file i should omit the NormalCalculator:: from the function declarations.
  Because now I'm being told
missing ';' before NormalCalculator::computeFaceNormals(........
in the .cpp file.

Comment: @GuyJoelMcLean yes, inside the class definition ( which is `class NormalCalculator{....};`) you don't qualify the methods with `NormalCalculator::`.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore could you perhaps also see a reason that  I'm being told 'missing ';' before NormalCalculator::computeFaceNormals(........'in the .cpp file? 

When i hover over the error squiggley red line, I'm still being told that identifier 'GLpoint' is undefined.

Comment: @GuyJoelMcLean did you include the file that defines GLPoint?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore yes it is a struct defined in NormalCalculator.h (in the code above). However I have since seen that for some reason the compiler thinks that the function has return type 'int'.
This is in the error log
error C2556: 'int NormalCalculator::computeFaceNormal(NormalCalculator::GLface)' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'NormalCalculator::GLpoint NormalCalculator::computeFaceNormal(NormalCalculator::GLface).

Are you sure it's okay to define a struct in a header file as i have done above?

Comment: @GuyJoelMcLean of course it's fine. If there's another error, post a new question.